# Reading and sending data from a micro SD card using Micro SD card adapter without using buffer

Tags: arduino-uno, data

Actually,  I am trying to get data that appears in a .wav file, but I got the problem that it is not as fast as I need because, looking around the SD library I found that most of the bits are saved into the buffer and when the buffer is filled its information is sent.
However, I do not want it to happen. I just need the bits to get readed and next to be sent as soon as possible witout saving in the buffer.
Do you know if is it actually possible, to modify the SD library to change the transmition's parameters because As I wrote previously I do not want the buffer to be used.

Comment: To my knowledge, it's a feature of SD cards. Data can only be read in sectors (512 byte). Of course it's possible to modify Arduino libraries, and e.g. combine reading and playing the music. I fear you will learn a lot but won't become happy.

Comment: buffering would not slow it down very much. if it's not fast enough, unless just barely, it's for a different reason.